# Simple python if/else syntax not working

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to create a simple test-scorer that grades your test and gives you a response - but a simple if/else function isn't running -

Python -

```
testScore = input("Please enter your test score")


if testScore <= 50:
  print "You didn't pass... sorry!" 
elif testScore >=60 and <=71:
  print "You passed, but you can do better!"
```

The Error is -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6
    elif testScore >= 60 and <= 71:
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Python is high-level but not straight-up English.. `elif testScore >=60 and <=71:` should be modified into this `elif 60 <= testScore <= 71:`

Comment: It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed testScore in elif statement

```
 testScore = input("Please enter your test score")


if testScore <= 50:
  print "You didn't pass... sorry!" 
elif testScore >=60 and testScore<=71:
  print "You passed, but you can do better!"
```

Answer (score 3):

The below shown way would be the better way of solving it, you always need to make the type conversion to integer when you are comparing/checking with numbers.

> input() in python would generally take as string

```
 testScore = input("Please enter your test score")
 if int(testScore) <= 50:
     print("You didn't pass... sorry!" )
 elif int(testScore) >=60 and int(testScore)<=71:
     print("You passed, but you can do better!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You made some mistakes here:

- You are comparing a string with an Integer `if testScore <= 50:`
- You have missed the variable here -->  `elif testScore >=60 and <=71:`

I think those should be like this --->

- `if int(testScore) <= 50:`
- `elif testScore >=60 and testScore<=71:`

And try this, it is working --->

```
testScore = input("Please enter your test score")
if int(testScore) <= 50:
    print ("You didn't pass... sorry!") 
elif testScore >=60 and testScore<=71:
    print ("You passed, but you can do better!")
```