# random.randint in python generate almost the same values

Tags: python, random, random-seed

Using random.randint I want to generate random integers between (1, 2, 3).
About 90% of times this function return 3, even I used random.seed(time.clock()).
After 100 iterations, the function returns :

- 5 Times number 1
- 7 Times number 2
- 88 Timer number 3

This is my code

```
def used_bin_packing_heuristic(self):
        #random.seed(time.clock())
        rnd = random.randint(1, 4)

        if rnd == 1:
            print('First fit used.')
            solution = self.customer_vehicle_allocation__first_fit()
        elif rnd == 2:
            print('Max rest used.')
            solution = self.customer_vehicle_allocation__max_rest()
        else:
            print('Next fit used.')
            solution = self.customer_vehicle_allocation__next_fit()
        return solution
```

Who can help me?

Comment: `randint` is *inclusive* on *both* ends. You're generating 1, 2, 3 or *4*, and *both* 3 and 4 end up in the `else` case. You want `rnd = random.randint(1, 3)` or `rnd = random.randrange(1, 4)`. That doesn't explain the ratios, but you *should not* be seeding Python's PRNG with the clock time; it already seeds from OS supplied crypto randomness automatically, so you're making it worse. I strongly suspect you're doing other things wrong too (because the actual PRNG is nowhere near this biased), probably in a misguided attempt to make it "more random".

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try this:

```
def used_bin_packing_heuristic(self):
    rnd = random.randint(1, 120)
    if rnd >= 10:
        rnd = 1
    if rnd >=11 and rnd <=20:
        rnd = 2
    if rnd >=21 and rnd <=30:
        rnd = 3
    if rnd >=31 and rnd <=40:
        rnd = 1
    if rnd >=41 and rnd <=50:
        rnd = 2
    if rnd >=51 and rnd <=60:
        rnd = 3
    if rnd >=61 and rnd <=70:
        rnd = 1
    if rnd >=71 and rnd <=80:
        rnd = 2
    if rnd >=81 and rnd <=90:
        rnd = 3
    if rnd >=91 and rnd <=100:
        rnd = 1
    if rnd >=101 and rnd <=110:
        rnd = 2
    if rnd >=111 and rnd <=120:
        rnd = 3
```

Comment: Why would you add this complication? Also, this is just wrong: `if rnd >=60 and <=31:` [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074966/simple-python-if-else-syntax-not-working)

Comment: @Mark figured it would make the number more random

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to think this would be more random (i.e. a more even distribution).